# Eigen having issues with variadic template expansion of the Rows template

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variadic-templates, eigen

I am trying to create a grid that uses an `Eigen:Matrix`; see [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) for library.

So let's take a look at a minimal piece of code:

```
template<typename Types, int... Sizes> class Grid;

template<typename... Types, int... Sizes>
class Grid<std::tuple<Types...>, Sizes...>
{
public:
    using grid_type = std::tuple<Eigen::Matrix<Types, Sizes, 1>...>;
};
```

and then in `main`, for example:

```
Grid<std::tuple<long, int>, -1, 10000>::grid_type;
```

I get the following three errors in VS2017 when compiling:

> Error C3548   '_Rows': parameter pack cannot be used in this context
>
> Error C2976   'Eigen::Matrix': too few template arguments
>
> Error C3546   '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand
>
> Error C3203   'Matrix': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Types', expected a real type

Now, if we were to use something like an `std::array` instead, then even with the -1 parameter everything is fine (well it's just converted to a positive `size_t`):

```
using grid_type = std::tuple<std::array<Types, Sizes>...>;
```

`grid_type` comes out as expected.

Now what is also bizzare, VS's intellisense is able to able to evaluate the Eigen version correctly, but it can't compile it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this compiles fine with GCC, clang, and ICC, but no luck with MSVC. Here is a nicer workaround for MSVC:

```
template<typename Scalar,int Rows>
using Mat = Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Rows, 1>;

using grid_type = std::tuple<Mat<Types,Sizes>...>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out. Because `Eigen::Matrix` uses default values for some of the constructor parameters, which in this case depend on the Rows/Cols parameter (where Rows is a variadic template) then the compiler gets confused. I explicitly listed out all the parameters, and it compiled:

```
using grid_type = std::tuple<Eigen::Matrix<Types, Sizes, 1, Eigen::AutoAlign | false, Sizes,1>...>;
```

However, this still doesn't satiate me, because it is wierd that intellisense can deal with this but the compiler cannot.